# How to update a Text cell using a ComboBox cell VB.NET DatagridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using `Friend WithEvents PersonName As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` as a column in DataGridView and `PersonName` `DataSoucre` is bounded to a database. I would like for when the `ComboBox` Selection is changed it uses that value to query my database Business Object to find the right value then I want to set the value from the query to the column to the right of the one with the `ComboBox` which is named `Colum3`.

But am not use how to access each individual event handler for the `ComboBox` cell, I tried `dgvTable.CellBeginEdit` but it triggers too early.

```
Private Sub dgvTable_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgvTable.CellBeginEdit
    If e.RowIndex <> -1 And e.ColumnIndex <> -1 Then
        dgvTable.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Colum3").Value = dgvTable.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value & "Somevalue from my databse"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the [CellValueChangedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=net-5.0). Also if you want to update your gridview from the database you have to update the DataSource since it will not happen autoamtically.

Comment: That´s not the whole truth, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652957/what-event-catches-a-change-of-value-in-a-combobox-in-a-datagridviewcell) how to get the changed value of the combobox

Comment: The [CellBeginEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit?view=net-5.0) event occurs when edit mode starts for the selected cell. So I don't think this event is the one you should use. Take a look at the links @AlexB. posted. You can also edit your question and give more details, eg. what your grid looks like, and an example of what you're trying to achive.